# Positioning adjacent elements

Tags: html, css, positioning

I'm trying to achieve the following effect:

```
+----------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+
| span (absolute left) | div consuming all space inbetween | span (absolute right) |
+----------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

On the surface it feels really straightforward; however:

- I don't want to set the width of the left/right elements (I want them to 'shrink-wrap' automatically); and
- I don't want to set the width of the all-consuming div (I want it to fill the arbitrary space).

I have been fiddling with relative positioning and floats for a while and am beginning to feel like I'm missing something obvious, since I'm so close.  I'd be grateful to be put out of my misery :)

(Using a table just occurred to me - I'll have another fiddle meanwhile.)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks bPratik!  I had an epiphany when I read: *floated columns begin "floating" at the point in the parent element's text where they first appear*.

The principle code I had was correct:

```
<div>
    <span style="float:left">span (float left)</span>
    <div>greedy div</div>
    <span style="float:right">span (float right)</span>
</div>
```

However, that creates the following:

```
+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+
| span (float left) |                  greedy div                   |
+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+
                                               | span (float right) |
                                               +--------------------+
```

Therefore, the order of elements has to be `span, span, div`, otherwise the right-floating span is forced onto the line beneath (by the greedy div stealing it's spot).

Hence, the solution:

```
<div>
    <span style="float:left">span (float left)</span>
    <span style="float:right">span (float right)</span>
    <div>greedy div</div>
</div>
```

And subsequent result:

```
+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+
| span (float left) |        greedy div        | span (float right) |
+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

I hope that's clear :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually have to use an HTML table element, instead you can style any element to behave just like a table using `display: table/table-row/table-cell`.